# Mostrar datos entre un rango de fechas utilizando Highcharts en Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, highcharts

**Edito la pregunta:**

Estoy usando `HighCharts` dentro de WordPress para mostrar datos de una DB `MySql`.

Quiero mostrar datos entre un rango de fechas seleccionado por el usuario

[image: input date html5]

En el código de `HighCharts`, en el apartado data no tengo datos estáticos sino dinámicos invocados de la DB de **WordPress**. Lo que quiero lograr es que el parametro sql **BETWEEN '2017-05-28' AND '2017-06-01'** tome el rango de fechas que el usuario seleccione en los input y no estas fechas estáticas.

No se si así sea mas clara mi inquietud!

Comment: +1 Buena pregunta, pero agrega el código con que muestras el gráfico por favor

Comment: tu problema no esta muy claro, es un json que recibe de php una fecha? es highchart? es php la duda en tu consulta?

Comment: tu pregunta es ejecutar un jquery para actualizar el grafico?

Comment: te recomiendo para fines practicos colocar en una sola parte el codigo php , armas el array y luego lo pintas donde debe de ir

Comment: @JackNavaRow. ¿Cómo lo hago? perdón pero apenas me inicio en programación y me falta mucho por aprender

Comment: @YESIDDOTNET creo que lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente busca como hacer un servicio rest en Wordpress (no soy el indicado) y aplicas el ejemplo que te envie, te quedara el codigo muy ordenado y comprenderas mas la programacion

Comment: Acabo de leer un poco al respecto, pero creo que me confundiría más de lo que estoy. De igual forma, gracias por la información, dedicaré tiempo a conocerla e implementarla. De momento, alguien conoce una forma aunque sea artesanal de hacer lo que requiero?

Comment: puedes hacer otra forma @YESIDDOTNET refrescar la misma ventana obteniendo los parametros por GET, voy a intentar hacerlo con lo que tienes

Comment: listo puedes intentar espero que te funcione

Comment: Estás haciendo 2 preguntas en 1 y te queda demasiado amplia ... Te recomiendo que preguntes una sola cosa a la vez para que podamos entenderte y darte una respuesta mas clara. Ejemplo: puedes preguntar Cómo obtienes las fechas seleccionadas desde jQuery en una pregunta y cómo las envías por AJAX en otra pregunta, cómo recibes un parámetro GET y haces la búsqueda en la base de datos.

Comment: Adriana, gracias por tu ayuda, trataré de mejorar mis preguntas futuras. Recién me inicio en programación y en esta gran comunidad.

Comment: Hola "YES ID DOT NET" espero puedas ver este comentario! Actualmente tengo el mismo problema que tu presentabas inicialmente, sin embargo tengo resuelta la consulta y la llamada de datos! Pero no se como hacer que me pinte los datos que obtengo en la gráfica, me gustaría saber de que manera lo hiciste tu a ver si me da una pista! Coloque de esta forma: chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4] ); }); Pero no funciona. También lo hice de esta manera, pero tampoco me sirve: chart.serie = data.serie Te agradecería mucho una pequeña or

Comment: @Carlos Marcano La verdad, lo hice con php y no se si de la mejor manera. `$variable1= $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE nombre_campo LIKE '%campo1%'AND created BETWEEN '$fechaini' AND '$fechafin'" );` `$variable2= $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE nombre_campo LIKE '%campo2%'AND created BETWEEN '$fechaini' AND '$fechafin'" );` Luego, en `series: [{
            name: 'Grafico',
            data: [
                <?php echo $variable1; ?>,
                <?php echo $variable2; ?>
            ]
        }]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me imagino que quieres pasar fechas en highcharts y actualizar tu grafico. si es esto aqui el ejemplo:

```js
$(function () {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container'
    },
    
    series: [{
      name : "mantequila",
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
  });
  
  
  $('#button').click(function() {
    //validamos las fechass
    var fecha_inicio = $('#inicio').val();
    var fecha_fin = $('#fin').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/",
      method: "GET",
      data: { fecha_inicio: fecha_inicio, fecha_fin: fecha_fin }
    }).done(function(data) {
      /* en mi caso esta en duro pero si recibes los valores deberian ser todos 
      as series por tanto deberia ser algo como 
      chart.serie = data.serie*/ 
      chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 
        148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 
        54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4] );
      });
      
      
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
fecha inicio<input type="text" id="inicio" name="inicio"/>
fecha fin <input type="text" id="fin" name="fin"/>
<button id="button">Agregar Fecha</button>
```

```
    $('#button').click(function() {
    //validamos las fechass
    var fecha_inicio = $('#inicio').val();
    var fecha_fin = $('#fin').val();
        $.ajax({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/",
        method: "GET",
        data: { fecha_inicio: fecha_inicio, fecha_fin: fecha_fin }
      }).done(function(data) {
      /* en mi caso esta en duro pero si recibes los valores deberian ser todos 
       as series por tanto deberia ser algo como 
       chart.serie = data.serie*/ 
        chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 
                                 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 
                                 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4] );
      });


    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5dszcfq7/1/
si quieres refrescar en wordpres mediante tu codigo es el siguiente (no lo he probado solo lo hice por logica):

```
<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="fechaini" style="width: 50%; display: inline-block;"><input type="date" name="fechafin" style="width: 50%; display: inline-block;">
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
<?php
$fecha_inicio = isset($_GET['fecha_inicio']) ? $_GET['fecha_inicio'] : '2017-05-28'
$fecha_fin = isset($_GET['fecha_fin']) ? $_GET['fecha_fin'] : '2017-06-01'
?>

<script>
[insert_php]
$fecha_inicio = isset($_GET['fecha_inicio']) ? $_GET['fecha_inicio'] : '2017-05-28'
$fecha_fin = isset($_GET['fecha_fin']) ? $_GET['fecha_fin'] : '2017-06-01'
global $wpdb;
$arregloDatos = [];
//parametro1
$arregloDatos[] = $wpdb->query( "SELECT * FROM nombre_de_tabla WHERE nombre_campo LIKE '%parametro1%'AND fecha_created BETWEEN '$fecha_inicio' AND '$fecha_fin'" );
//parametro2
$arregloDatos[] = $wpdb->query( "SELECT * FROM nombre_de_tabla WHERE nombre_campo LIKE '%parametro2%'AND fecha_created BETWEEN '$fecha_inicio' AND '$fecha_fin'" );
//parametro3
$arregloDatos[] = $wpdb->query( "SELECT * FROM nombre_de_tabla WHERE nombre_campo LIKE '%parametro3%'AND fecha_created BETWEEN '$fecha_inicio' AND '$fecha_fin'" );
//parametro4
$arregloDatos[] = $wpdb->query( "SELECT * FROM nombre_de_tabla WHERE nombre_campo LIKE '%parametro4%'AND fecha_created BETWEEN '$fecha_inicio' AND '$fecha_fin'");
//parametro5
$arregloDatos[]= $wpdb->query( "SELECT * FROM nombre_de_tabla WHERE nombre_campo LIKE '%parametro5%' AND fecha_created BETWEEN '$fecha_inicio' AND '$fecha_fin'" );
//arreglo a cadena separados por comas
$totalGrafico = implode(",", $arregloDatos);
[/insert_php]


$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Titulo',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Subtitulo',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['parametro1', 'parametro2', 'parametro3', 'parametro4', 'parametro5']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Cantidad'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ''
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'nombre_serie',
        data: [
        [insert_php]
        echo $totalGrafico;
        [/insert_php]

]
    }]
});
});
</script>
<form method="GET" action="miURL">
fecha inicio<input type="text" id="fecha_inicio" name="fecha_inicio"/>
fecha fin <input type="text" id="fecha_fin" name="fecha_fin"/>
<input type="submit">cambiar fecha</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hola @JackNavaRow. Lo que planteas se aproxima a lo que requiero. Voy a plantearlo de otra manera y comparto el código que tengo para que sea mas clara mi inquietud.

Comment: Hola JackNavaRow. Tu idea me ayudo demasiado a aclarar mi duda. Finalmente logré hacerlo usando `isset`. Publicaré la solución como una respuesta. Mil gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Perdón por mi ignorancia, no se como hacer +1. Hago clic en los íconos de **"esta respuesta es útil"** y me dice que no se mostrará al publico por tener menos de 15 puntos de reputación.

Comment: ya cerrastes la respuesta tambien es bueno!

Answer (score 1):

Pues bien, la respuesta de @JackNavaRow me ayudó a aclarar mi duda.

La solución está en el siguiente bloque de código:

```
//Formulario en html5
<form method="post">
<label for="fechaini" style="width: 50%; display: inline-block;">Fecha Inicial</label><label for="fechafin" style="width: 50%; display: inline-block;">Fecha Final</label>
<input type="date" name="fechaini" style="width: 50%; display: inline-block;"><input type="date" name="fechafin" style="width: 50%; display: inline-block;">
<br><input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Generar Gráfica" style="float: right;">
</form>

//Código en php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['fechaini'])){
$fechaini = $_POST['fechaini'];
}
if(isset($_POST['fechafin'])){
$fechafin = $_POST['fechafin'];
}
?>
```

La primera parte es un formulario Html5 que envía a php las fechas seleccionadas por el usuario a través del metodo post. En la segunda parte se capturan las fechas con las variables de php $fechaini y $fechafin

Finalmente se usan estas variables en la sentencia SQL **BETWEEN '$fechaini' AND '$fechafin'**

[image: Al cargar la pagina]
[image: Al enviar las fechas]

Answer (score -1):

si lo que quieres hacer es que cuando el usuario cambie la fecha se vea actualizado tu chart. Lo que debes hacer es tener 2 páginas:
La primera con el rango de fechas que vaya a manipular el usuario, y la segunda embebida en la primera y recibiendo las variables de fechas, para que cuando el usuario cambie los rangos hagas un **REFRESH** a la pagina que contiene el script del Highchart. Esto fue lo que hice para un proyecto hace tiempo.

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: hay mucha misericordia por esta respuesta XD

Comment: No me parece buena esta respuesta

Comment: @Rostan, tu información me vendría bien para una etapa posterior a la que estoy enfrentando. No responde directamente a mi pregunta inicial pero me parece interesante lo que planteas. ¿Cómo puedo embeberla y que reciba las variables de las fechas?

Comment: Gracias por tu amable comentario. Te lo explique de esa forma, ya que no había información mas completa al inicio de la pregunta, como en que lenguaje trabajas o el código en si. Si pudieses ayudarme con esas cosas podría plantearte una mejor solución si se encuentra dentro de mis conocimientos. De antemano te digo que yo lo resolví con una herramienta que usa como compilador C#, Genexus. Saludos.

Comment: @Rostan, HighCharts es una librería desarrollada en jquery. Los input de las fechas las tengo actualmente en HTML5 por la facilidad de generar los datepicker (pero podrían cambiarse a jquery de ser necesario). Los query están escritos para MySql y están invocando datos a través de php... (No se si me estoy enredando con la cantidad de lenguajes que estoy usando, pero apenas me inicio en programación web.)